# No compatible version of java 1.5 is available

Tags: mac, java

First thanks for reading my post and willing to help.

I'm trying to run a program (MultiWiiConf 2.4, last version now) on my Mac (Sierra 10.12.6) but it won't launch and error `No compatible version of java 1.5 is available` is raised.

Then, after searching the web, I checked Java parameters and I have version 9.0.1 installed. The main thing that I don't understand is that java is supposed to be installed in /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/, but this folder is actually empty.

Moreover command line "java -version" returns :

```
Unable to locate a Java Runtime to invoke.
```

So I suppose that Java is not well installed but I tried to uninstall and reinstall it, updated it, problem still the same.

Could anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java 1.5 is very old and is not available for current macOS - I think it predates 10.6. Java 6 came out in 2006

You can get Java 6 from Apple and Java 7.8 or 9 from Oracle.

As for where java is installed. It's complex. `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins` is for web app Java not from Apple this would not set a Java in the terminal.

The java -version result implies that you do not have any Java installed.

First step is to ask the program's author where you can get a modern version of their app from which does not use an insecure unsupported version of Java. Then install that Java

Answer (score -2):

You are getting that command line error because to execute Java you need the full JDK

From [Java.com](https://java.com/en/download/faq/java_mac.xml#cmdline)

> **When I try to use java from the command line, why doesn't it work? I
> have Oracle's version of the JRE installed.**
>
> Installing a JRE from Oracle does not update java -version symlinks or
> add java to your path. For this functionality, you must install the
> full JDK.

> The main thing that I don't understand is that java is supposed to be
> installed in /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/, but this folder is actually
> empty.

There's a difference between the JRE (Java Runtime Environment) and the Java Internet Plugins. Downloading and installing Java allows you to launch Java applets on web pages, it doesn't give you access to execute Java apps via the command line.  To compile and execute Java applications (like the MultiWii controller software), you need the JDK.